# Why can't a variable be moved out of a closure?

Tags: function, lambda, rust, move-semantics, lifetime

I have the following function:

```rust
pub fn map_option<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
    Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
        opt_a.map(|a| a2b(a))
    })
}
```

However, this was quite difficult to write.  I started off with something simpler that didn't work, but I don't understand why it didn't work.

1. Here is my first version:

   ```rust
   pub fn map_option_1<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
       Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
           opt_a.map(a2b)
       })
   }
   ```

   This gave me the following error:

   ```
   error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a2b`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
     --> src/lib.rs:11:19
      |
   9  | pub fn map_option_1<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
      |                                              --- captured outer variable
   10 |     Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
   11 |         opt_a.map(a2b)
      |                   ^^^ move occurs because `a2b` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(A) -> B>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   ```
2. I thought that I might need to `move` the closure, so that it gets ownership of `a2b`:

   ```rust
   pub fn map_option_2<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
       Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
           opt_a.map(a2b)
       })
   }
   ```

   However, this also didn't work.  It failed with the following message:

   ```
   error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a2b`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
     --> src/lib.rs:17:19
      |
   15 | pub fn map_option_2<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
      |                                              --- captured outer variable
   16 |     Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
   17 |         opt_a.map(a2b)
      |                   ^^^ move occurs because `a2b` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(A) -> B>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   ```

   This error message says that `a2b` doesn't implement `Copy`, which I guess makes sense, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.
3. Out of desperation, I tried the following:

   ```rust
   pub fn map_option_3<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
       Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
           opt_a.map(|a| a2b(a))
       })
   }
   ```

   This at least gave me a different error:

   ```
   error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `a2b`, which is owned by the current function
     --> src/lib.rs:22:14
      |
   22 |     Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
      |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `a2b`
   23 |         opt_a.map(|a| a2b(a))
      |                       --- `a2b` is borrowed here
      |
   note: closure is returned here
     --> src/lib.rs:22:5
      |
   22 | /     Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
   23 | |         opt_a.map(|a| a2b(a))
   24 | |     })
      | |______^
   help: to force the closure to take ownership of `a2b` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
      |
   22 |     Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
      |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   The problem with ownership makes sense, I guess.  This is what led me to the solution above that actually works.
4. One other thing I tried that didn't work is the following:

   ```rust
   pub fn map_option_4<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
       Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
           opt_a.map(move |a| a2b(a))
       })
   }
   ```

   This gave me the following error:

   ```
   error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a2b`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
     --> src/lib.rs:29:19
      |
   27 | pub fn map_option_4<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
      |                                              --- captured outer variable
   28 |     Box::new(|opt_a: Option<A>| {
   29 |         opt_a.map(move |a| a2b(a))
      |                   ^^^^^^^^ ---
      |                   |        |
      |                   |        move occurs because `a2b` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(A) -> B>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
      |                   |        move occurs due to use in closure
      |                   move out of `a2b` occurs here
   ```

Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9115d5baf0d464eaa9221a05c9dc0806) with each of these functions.

---

I don't think I have a good enough understanding of lifetimes and ownership to see why each of these functions fail.

I can sort of understand how `map_option_1` and `map_option_3` fail, because `move` is not being used to explicitly move ownership, but I am surprised that `map_option_2` and `map_option_4` fail.

I am *very* surprised that `map_option_2` doesn't work, but the actual `map_option` function works.  To me, these are practically the same function.

*Why do each of these `map_option_X` functions fail to compile*??

Comment: I am also getting warnings that look like the following: `trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated`.  It recommends using types like `Box<dyn Fn(A) -> B>` instead of `Box<Fn(A) -> B>`.  I didn't actually check if this is related.

Comment: The presence or absence of `dyn` doesn't change the semantics of the program.

Comment: I should add that this question was inspired by the following Codewars problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5922543bf9c15705d0000020/rust

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that I might need to `move` the closure, so that it gets ownership of `a2b`

That's correct, you do need the `move` on the outer closure. Without `move`, the closure would capture `a2b` by reference. However, `a2b` is a local parameter, and returning a closure which has a reference to a local is invalid.

Adding `move` to the inner closure leads to an error because the function returns an `Fn` closure. For this argument, let's consider this `map_option_5` function:

```
pub fn map_option_5<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
    Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
        opt_a.map(move |a| a2b(a))
    })
}
```

If the inner closure captures `a2b` by value and the outer closure is also a `move` closure, then both closures end up capturing `a2b` by value. By the rules of ownership, only one of the closures can possibly own `a2b` at a time, so when the outer closure is called, it moves `a2b` out of itself (destructuring the outer closure) and into the inner closure (which is only possible for `FnOnce` closures, as they take `self` rather than `&mut self` or `&self`). The reason for the error message is that we are returning an `Fn` closure, not an `FnOnce` closure. We could indeed fix this by returning an `FnOnce` closure (but then it couldn't be called more than once):

```
pub fn map_option_5a<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<FnOnce(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
    Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
        opt_a.map(move |a| a2b(a))
    })
}
```

---

Now, let's discuss why `map_option` works while `map_option_2` doesn't. The problem stems from the fact that [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) takes ownership of the closure argument. Thus, we end up in a situation similar to `map_option_5` above. `Option::map` takes an `FnOnce`, because it only needs to call it at most once. Changing `a2b` to be a `Box<FnOnce(A) -> B>` wouldn't help though, because it can actually be used in many calls to `map`.

There's a way to avoid the inner closure: pass a reference to `a2b` to `map`. This works because

1. [`Box<F> where F: Fn<A>` implements `Fn<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#implementors) and
2. [`&F where F: Fn<A>` implements `FnOnce<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#implementors) (and also `Fn<A>`, though that's irrelevant here).

```
pub fn map_option_2a<A: 'static, B: 'static> (a2b: Box<Fn(A) -> B>) -> Box<Fn(Option<A>) -> Option<B>> {
    Box::new(move |opt_a: Option<A>| {
        opt_a.map(&a2b)
    })
}
```

The closure still takes ownership of `a2b`, but it doesn't *consume* it when it's called, so the closure can be called multiple times.

`map_option` works because its outer closure doesn't need to consume `a2b`. The inner closure captures `a2b` by reference from the outer closure. This works because [calling an `Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call) closure only needs a shared reference to the closure.